# Incompatible Types. Required: java.lang.String[] Found: java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to code an app that can pick the color from a picture selected from a gallery. When coding one of the overrides, I got this message.

```
Incompatible types.

Required: java.lang.String[]

Found: java.lang.String
```

The code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivity(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null !=data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = (MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in this `onActivity` method. How do I fix this error?

Comment: By not assigning a `String` to a variable of type `String[]`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What do you mean?

Comment: Everytime I try to type String[] it brings back an error

Comment: Then don't do that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] filePathColumn = (MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

This line attempts to create an array by placing a string in parentheses `()`.  But the parentheses only clarify order of operations; here they do nothing.

To create an array, wrap it in braces `{}` as an array initializer.

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
```

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` is just a String object, not an Array of Strings. So assigning it to a `String []` raises the error. It's like saying a page is equal to a book.

You can solve this using two ways:

1. Use braces to initialize the array with the value in-line:

   ```
   String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   ```
2. Or do it separately:

   ```
   String[] filePathColumn = new String[1];
   filePathColumn[0] = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
   ```